# Escape from DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I have a window that get its data from another class that is passed as DataContext. But I now also want to do data binding within the window. The window looks as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1"
    Height="300"
    Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="TestTextBlock"
                   Text="Hello World" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="TestTextBlock2" 
                   Text="{Binding ElementName=TestTextBlock,Path=Text}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The binding between the text blocks TestTextBlock and TestTextBlock2 works fine, but only until I change the DataContext-property of the window. How can I bind between those two textblocks so that changing the DataContext will not break the data binding?

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Comment: I'm not experiencing any problem. What actually happens when you change the `Window`'s `DataContext`? Are you changing `TestTextBlock.Text` programmatically ever?

Comment: Another question: You are changing the `DataContext` by assigning an entirely new object to it, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Binding.Mode to **OneTime** explicitly.
That way, TestTextBlock2.Text will only be set once (if that's what you want).